# Mysterious source of output in R?

Tags: r

I am using following code using mtcars data and factanal function for factor analysis. The print of fit$loadings give the proportional variance but it does not seem to be there in str(fit$loadings) :

```
> fit <- factanal(mtcars, 3, rotation="varimax")
> fit$loadings

Loadings:
     Factor1 Factor2 Factor3
mpg   0.643  -0.478  -0.473 
cyl  -0.618   0.703   0.261 
disp -0.719   0.537   0.323 
hp   -0.291   0.725   0.513 
drat  0.804  -0.241         
wt   -0.778   0.248   0.524 
qsec -0.177  -0.946  -0.151 
vs    0.295  -0.805  -0.204 
am    0.880                 
gear  0.908           0.224 
carb  0.114   0.559   0.719 

               Factor1 Factor2 Factor3
SS loadings      4.380   3.520   1.578
Proportion Var   0.398   0.320   0.143  <<<<<<<<<<<<< I NEED THESE NUMBERS AS A VECTOR
Cumulative Var   0.398   0.718   0.862
> 
> str(fit$loadings)
 loadings [1:11, 1:3] 0.643 -0.618 -0.719 -0.291 0.804 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:11] "mpg" "cyl" "disp" "hp" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "Factor1" "Factor2" "Factor3"
```

How can I get Proportional variance vector from fit$loadings? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `obj <- fit$loadings`. Here is a complete path how to obtain the result.

By writing `fit$loadings` (or `obj`) we actually call `print(obj)`. So, after looking at `str`, you might want to check what does the specific `print` method do with `obj`. To know what method we should look for, we check `class(obj)` and get `"loadings"`.

Then, writing `print.loadings` does not give anything because the function is hidden. Therefore, since function `factanal` is in the package `stats`, we call `stats:::print.loadings` and get a complete source code of the function. By inspecting it, we see that we can get the desired result as follows.

```
colSums(obj^2) / nrow(obj)
#   Factor1   Factor2   Factor3 
# 0.3982190 0.3199652 0.1434125
```

Comment: Was about to post identical answer. Another option to get to source is `getAnywhere(print.loadings)`.